# calc/excel if find text in two cells and output text

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

This is probably too simple but I just can't find my way around it. 
I have to cells

```
  A1              B1
high ground     low water
```

So I need a formula that states that if cell A1 contains "high ground" and cell B1 contains the word "water" output "OK" otherwise "no ok"

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with openoffice, but try `=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*high ground*")+COUNTIF(B1,"*water*")=2,"OK","NOT OK")` or `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("high ground",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("water",B1))),"OK","NOT OK")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OpenOffice / LibreOffice Calc, the following function should work:

> `=IF(AND(A1 = "high ground";NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("water";B1;1))));"OK";"not OK")`

or split up on multiple lines with comments:

> ```
> =IF(                                   # First function: result will depend on condition
>     AND(                               # Condition: two sub-conditions have to be TRUE
>         A1 = "high ground";            # First subcondition: simple equality check
>         NOT(                           # Second subcondition
>             ISERROR(                   # Check if the embededded function (SEARCH()) returns an error
>                 SEARCH("water";B1;1)   # Search B1 for substring. Will throw an error if there's no match in B! for string "water"
>             )
>         )
>     );
>     "OK";                              # Return value if condition is fulfilled;
>     "not OK"                           # return value if on of the sub-conditions isn't fulfilled.
> )
> ```

The `NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("water";B1;1)))` is a little bit complicated. Since the [**`SEARCH()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_SEARCH_function) function (as well as the [**`FIND()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_FIND_function) function) throws an error if there's no match, you will have to handle that error, else the complete formula will return an error instead of the string "not ok". For error handling, i put the `SEARCH()` function into an [**`ISERROR()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_ISERROR_function) function, translating the result of `SEARCH()` into a boolean value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`). Since we want a `TRUE` result if the search finds a match, we have to "invert" the output of `ISERROR()` using the [**`NOT()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_NOT_function) function.

Searching for a substring could also be done using regular expressions, but this would require enabling regular expressions in the Calc Program Options; the proposed solution using `ISERROR(SEARCH())` should work independently of that config setting.

Comment: Now I need to proccess about 4000 lines and I am using this filter over and over again to get different the outputs I need but at some point calc exeeds it limits and gives me an error, possibly because I use too much. I am wondering how to deal with this...

Answer (score 1):

Next formula is working for me:

=if(AND(A2="high ground",(B2=SEARCH("water",B2,1))>0),"ok","not ok")

I'm supposing cell A2 contains high groud, and cell B2 contains low water.

In the if statement there are two conditions: if cell A2= High ground and if cell b2 contains water then Ok else not ok.

Hope it works for you!!

Sorry, next is the right one (whithout HALLAR, instead SEARCH):

please try next:

=IF(AND(A1="high ground",(B1=SEARCH("water",B1,1))>0),"ok","not ok"

Comment: sorry the correct formula is next (without HALLAR instead SEARCH):      =IF(AND(A1="high ground",(B1=SEARCH("water",B1,1))>0),"ok","not ok")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=if(AND(A1="high ground",B1="*water*"),"OK","Not OK")
```

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't provide an answer?

Comment: Hi all, none of these seem to work. in calc I get an 501 error and in excel 2007 a dialog pops up stating an error in the formula. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You may have to replace the argument-separating commata by semicola. This depends on the calc language settings. With language set to english (US), the following formula works: `=IF(AND(A1 = "high ground";B1 = "low water");"OK"; "not OK")`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my answer before included a wildcard within an If statement and for some reason excel doesn't recognise them.

I have tested this one and it should work for you:

`=IF(AND(A1="high ground",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("water",B1))),"OK","Not OK")`